# Файл gitIgnore не правильно работает в Android sTudio

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

GitIgnore файл не правильно игнорирует файлы. Что делать?

Comment: Это те файлы, которые не отслеживаются git. И вы не правильно написали .gradle - это простая абстракция студии же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git не работает с каталогами. Git работает с файлами.

Ваша запись означает, что если бы в корне проекта был бы файл `.gradle`, то он был бы проигнорирован.

Для того чтобы отключить слежение за файлами в каталоге `.gradle` нужно использовать конструкцию `/.gradle/**`